# Using Connect Multiparty, Jimp and Amazon s3fs node modules to upload resized photo to Amazon s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-resizing

I currently have the following code set up to send a file from the client to an express server.

```
      const data = new FormData()
      data.append('programPhoto', imageFromFileInput, fileName)

      $.ajax({
        url: requestUrl,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST'
      })
```

On the server I'm using Connect-Multiparty to get this image file on the req object as req.files[0]

```
    const multiParty = require('connect-multiparty');
    const multiPartyMiddleware = multiParty();
    app.use(multiPartyMiddleware);
```

I have a helper function that takes the file and uploads it to amazon s3 successfully and works great. It looks like this:

```
    const constants = require('../config/constants');
    const keys = require('../config/config.js')
    const fs = require('fs');
    const S3FS = require('s3fs');
    const Jimp = require('jimp')

    const s3fsImp1 = new S3FS(constants.BUCKET_NAME, {
        accessKeyId: keys.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: keys.AWS_SECRET_KEY
    });

const uploadToAmazonS3 = function(file) {
      const stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
      const programName = file.originalFilename.split('_')[0];
      // setting a fileName to make a useful URL
      const fileName = programName;

      return s3fsImp1.writeFile(fileName, stream)
        .then(function() {
          fs.unlink(file.path, function(err) {
            if (err) {
              console.error('error uploading to s3 ', err);
            }
          })
          const encodedFilename = fileName.replace(/ /gi, '+');
          const url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/' + constants.BUCKET_NAME + '/' + encodedFilename;
          console.log('uploaded to s3. URL: ', url);
          // return image URL and photoId from DB so we can find the row by ID and update the URL
          return { url: url, Id: photoId };
        })
        .catch(function() {
            console.error('error uploading to S3')
        })
 }
```

This code is working well and photos are uploading and the URLs are matching up correctly, however I now need to resize or crop the images before uploading to S3. I am attempting to use the Jimp npm module

From the docs, the basic usage of Jimp is as follows:

```
Jimp.read("./path/to/image.jpg").then(function (image) {
    // do something with the image, example:
    return image.resize(250, 250)
                .quality(60)
}).catch(function (err) {
    // handle an exception
});
```

Jimp can also read a buffer:

```
Jimp.read(lenna.buffer, function (err, image) {
    // do stuff with the image (if no exception)
});
```

However no matter how I adjust the code to work it into the chain of events leading up to uploading to S3, I am not able to get the Jimp module to read the file I sent through connect-multiparty. The file object looks like this:

```
{ fieldName: 'programPhoto',
    originalFilename: 'Screen Shot 2016-04-10 at 12.20.50 PM.png',
    path: '/var/folders/rl/b20b02js419dvh736nkydw6w0000gn/T/ROo9HeqPYBggfTZ1tUK7Zdkx.png',
  headers:
     { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="programPhoto"; filename="Screen Shot 2016-04-10 at 12.20.50 PM.png"',
     'content-type': 'image/png' },
    size: 184932,
    name: 'Screen Shot 2016-04-10 at 12.20.50 PM.png',
    type: 'image/png' }
```

if I try to do 
    Jimp.read(file.path).then(function (image) {
        // do stuff
    }).catch(function (error) {
       console.error('error reading with Jimp ', error);
    })

I get the following error logged:

```
error reading with Jimp Jimp {
    _originalMime: 'image/png',
    bitmap:
   { data: <Buffer dc dd dd ff dc dd dd ff dc dd dd ff dc dd dd ff dc dd dd ff dc dd dd ff dc dd dd ff dc dd dd ff dc dd dd ff dc dd dd ff dc dd dd ff dc dd dd ff dc dd ... >,
       width: 568,
       height: 414 } }
```

I would really like to use this object on the request file with Jimp, is there anyway this will be possible without changing the way I am sending the file to the server?

Comment: If in case you have resolved this issue. Can you please let me know the solution? Thank you.